# Where can I get a list of 4th edition D&D acronyms?

Tags: dnd-4e, terminology

I'd like to have a simple reference sheet for this, as people will frequently reference sourcebooks with a simple acronym. Perhaps this question can be made into such a sheet.

Most have been easy to find, some that come to mind are:

- DMG*: Dungeon Master's Guide (I, II, II, etc)
- PHB*: Player's Handbook (I, II, III, etc)
- HotFL: Heroes of the Fallen Lands
- HotEC: Heroes of the Elemental Chaos
- HotFW: Heroes of the Feywild
- Heroes of the Adjective Noun: Books like the above, essentially extensions of the PHBs

But I started this question because Google has failed me, what is AV2 for?

- AV2: ???

Any others worth mentioning?

Comment: Do you want acronyms in general or acronyms for the book names? You should probably scope this question to the latter if that's what you're after

Comment: Do not use comments to answer the question.

Comment: Googling `av2 4e` answers the question. What are you having trouble with? Or is your actual question that you just really want a catalogue of D&D products and their acronyms?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- A general consensus abbreviation book list is [here](http://community.wizards.com/comment/17385881#comment-17385881);
- A forum glossary is [here](http://community.wizards.com/forum/community-business/threads/1716881); and
- A general concept glossary is [here](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/3126371).

All of these links have been derived from the [complete collection of character build links](http://community.wizards.com/forum/4e-character-optimization/threads/1478896).

Answer (score 1):

Brian Ballsun-Stanton has really great links you should check out in his answer. But, just so people don't have to go combing through lists if they don't want to, I wanted to add that the acronym in question "AV2" refers to "Adventurer's Vault 2". It is a sequel (obviously) to the "Adventurer's Vault" resource book. Both add loads of gear for use in your games with an eye toward magic items.